# Role-dependent associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design, activerecord

I am working on my first real Rails app for timetracking in a company and I have run into database/model design concern. My app has a User model and a Role model which are linked together through a has_and_belongs_to_many association.

One of the roles is the manager. A manager can have many assistants and assistants can have many managers (although typically only one). This relationship is represented through a manager_assistant_relationship expressed in the User model as:

```
has_many :assistants, :through => :manager_assistant_relationships
has_many :managers, :through => :manager_assistant_relationships
```

Assistants can have many shifts (a different model representing a work shift) and managers can have many clients (another model that will be billed for the assistants' work). And more associations are coming.

As far as I can tell the only solution is to put all these relationships in the User model, but something feels wrong about this and the User model could get bloated as roles increases and associations mount and it also seems unintuitive, because a User only has many assistants if he is a manager. I would like some advice about potential pitfalls to this approach and what alternatives I should consider.

Would it be a good idea to subclass the User model into roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, you're doing it correctly with roles.

To answer your question, *no* it is not a good idea to subclass the User model for what you describe. If you did, it tends to lead to tricky self-joins for associations, or to STI (single table inheritance), or to inheritance or classes instead of composition of modules. Much better to use roles.

It may help you to think of the user as a person, not a role. So the User class contains just personal information, such as name, birthdate, height, and maybe an email address, sign in password, etc. Make the personal information separate from the time tracking role.

To use your roles, you can do model relationships like this psuedocode:

```
 class Manager
   has_many :clients
 end

 manager = Manager.find(id)
 client = manager.clients.first
```

Or like this pseudocode:

```
 class Assistant
   has_many :workshifts
 end

 assistant = Assistant.find(id)
 workshift = assistant.workshifts
```

Other good reasons to prefer using roles is for [Role-Based Access Control (RBAC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) and for [Data Context Interation (DCI)](http://www.artima.com/articles/dci_vision.html)  if you want to read up on these.

Comment: Maybe I haven't expressed myself concisely or maybe I am reading you wrong, but I am not thinking about doing STI with a type column. I am thinking about subclassing the User model using a default_scope instead. So for instance I have:

`class Assistant < User
  default_scope joins(:roles).where(:roles => {name: 'assistant'})
  has_many :managers, :through => :manager_assistant_relationships
end`

The table is still User, but by subclassing I can write Assistant.find(123) rather than User.scope_assistant.find(123).
This allows me to move role-specific associations to the role.

Comment: Is that in line with what you'd recommend?

Comment: @Niels I understand you; I added more to the answer to help.

Comment: @joelparkerhenderson in this u have mentioned to made like: class Manager
   has_many :clients
 end But i cant understand how we gonna define manager as it is user and here manager is new active record. Can you just clear me up

Comment: @Usar Can you explain more about what you're asking, and what aspects of the question and answer that you do understand, and do not understand? This will help me figure out how to answer you. Thanks!