# Relationship between different Devise+Cancan roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am implementing an authentication+authorization system in my Rails 3 Application.
I have a HABTM relationship with between Users and Roles.

The roles I will have are : manager,dealer,operator,admin

Now a manager can have many dealers under him. How do I model this relationship?

It is a simple question but I could not find an answer. Also a similar question here: [Role-dependent associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521031/role-dependent-associations) but it does not clear things properly.

### **EDIT**:

I am thinking my requirement is further simple. For me a user can only be either an Admin, Operator, Dealer or Manager.

For this I can simply add a role column to User table. How will the relationship between Managers and Dealers be enforced now?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something more like

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :managers
  has_many :dealer
  has_many :admins
  has_many :operators
  has_many :dealer_users, :through => :managers, :class_name=>"User"
end

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  belongs_to :user
end

class Dealer
  has_many :organizations
  belongs_to :user
end

class Operator < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  belongs_to :user
end

class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :dealers
  belongs_to :organization
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  has_many :admins
  has_many :operators
  has_many :managers
  has_many :dealers
end
```

Comment: Can I do without an Organisation model?

Comment: Yes you can do without that too. However I assumed that the roles that you have like manager, operator etc should belong to some top level system may be an organization. So this is general relationship as far for you to get an idea to continue.

Comment: what to do incase I have a user with single role? How would the implementation look like den?